Authentication in Next.js
I want to add different kinds of authentication in my Next.js project. What should I use for it? Next/Auth or Firebase or something else? According to my knowledge, Next/Auth doesn't provide any direct authentication method by email & password. We need to save the user in the backend first, then we have to match the user's email & password with the database, and then we can log in by using Next/Auth Credentials Provider. But is there any simple and efficient way for the authentication that I can use in my Next.js project just like firebase? **

If yes, then please share with me with proper documentation.

**
